# Node-red error : udp.errors.alreadyused

Tags: node.js, udp, node-red

red, everything was working fine with node-red and UDP but suddenly on restart of node-red im receiving this error

> udp.errors.alreadyused

please help me

Comment: That means you have another (maybe orphaned) process using that same port -- did you add another UDP node and not give it a unique port number? If you are using Linux, you can find a list of what processes are using the UDP ports by running the command `netstat -leu` -- if node-red is not running, then your port should not be listed as active.

Comment: Thank you steveR. this command list few UDP process but all are closed and im using 2 ports for UDP communication "51700" and "51701" but 51701 is not listing..

Comment: Did you run the netstat command while node-red is stopped? If so, then you should NOT see either one listed. So if 51700 **is** listed while node-red is stopped, use the pid to find the process that is using that port and kill it (or change its config to use another port).

Answer (score 0):

Probably not finished connection.
Try:
  deploy => full
  deploy => restart flows

it still
Menu => configuration Nodes
Select udp node and press Update.
(this close al connection and restart the node)

[node-red restart flows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1aca.jpg)